# Multiple Column lookup and return corresponding value in next column (nearest value)

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

Here's what I am trying to accomplish, I have two sheets:

Reference Sheet:
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCWPn.jpg)

> ```
> Code     Length     Width     Height
>
> A         78         48        25     
> B         78         48        34 
> C         12         7.4        5
> D         12         15         5
> E         12         15       7.5
> F         12         15         9
> G         24         15         5
> H         24         15         7
> ```

**Solution Sheet:**

[Click to see solution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTN7w.jpg)

> ```
> Length    Width   Height  Returning Code   Match_L   Match_W   Match_H
>
>  10        6       8         C                12        7.4        5
> ```

The formula in Column "Returning Code" should look for the nearest value in the corresponding Reference Sheet i.e., Length <-> Length, Width <-> Width, Height <-> Height and return the matching "Code" from the corresponding row.

It would have been simpler if I want to match it when the values are equal but in my case, it will be looking for the nearest value (either greater or lower) in each of the corresponding columns and return the matching "Code" and the values in Match_L, Match_W, Match_H columns.

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you already tried, and where did this fail? Are you looking for a solution in VBA? If so what code do you already have? Is the difference in either direction treated equally, just as an absolute difference, or can difference even eachother out?

Comment: You have two sheets, in this sheet, you will enter `ReturningCode` and remaining values will automatically populate from another sheet. is it right? Please explain a bit more, what is the input and what will be the expected output.

Comment: @MIdrees I will enter the Length, Width and Height and it should return "Code" . In the example, I have entered L=10, W=6, H=8 and nearest matching values are in "C" with L=12, =7.4 and H=5. All three values should match!

Comment: @Luuklag Difference in either direction is treated equally, absolute difference. I'm not looking for a VBA solution but any general solve will be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following VBA will do this job.

```
Sub LookupNearestValue()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim i As Long, RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 2

    Dim tRowCounter As Long
    Dim tValue As Long
    Dim tempValue As Long

    Dim tLength As Long, tWidth As Long, tHeight As Long
    Dim tempLength As Long, tempWidth As Long, tempHeight As Long

    tLength = ws.Cells(2, 6)
    tWidth = ws.Cells(2, 7).Value
    tHeight = ws.Cells(2, 8).Value

    With ws
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            tempLength = ws.Cells(RowCounter, 2)
            tempWidth = ws.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value
            tempHeight = ws.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value

            tempValue = Abs(tLength - tempLength) + Abs(tWidth - tempWidth) + Abs(tHeight - tempHeight)

            If RowCounter = 2 Then
                tValue = tempValue
                tRowCounter = RowCounter
            ElseIf RowCounter > 2 And tempValue < tValue Then
                tValue = tempValue
                tRowCounter = RowCounter
            End If

            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        Next i

        ws.Cells(2, 9) = ws.Cells(tRowCounter, 1)
        ws.Cells(2, 10) = ws.Cells(tRowCounter, 2)
        ws.Cells(2, 11) = ws.Cells(tRowCounter, 3).Value
        ws.Cells(2, 12) = ws.Cells(tRowCounter, 4).Value


    End With

End Sub
```

To make this Macro work, you need to have data on sheet according to these columns arrangement:

[image]

In my sheet, I have setup to run this macro on value change event in `H2` cell.

Comment: Thank you @M_Idrees This helps a lot!

Comment: Welcome, Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is only a single place for entering the required length, width and height, and thus only one returned value at its maximum:

In your reference sheet add three more columns in E to G: `length_dif`, `width_dif` and `height_dif`.

The formula for these columns will be in cell E2: `=ABS(B2-SolutionSheet!A$2)` then expand this to G2 and draw it down till the end of your solution table.

Add another column in your reference sheet in H: `dif_abs` with the formula: `=Sum(E2:G2)`

Then to return your value add the following formula in your SolutionSheet in cell D2: `=Index(ReferenceSheet!$A$2:$H$9;MATCH(Min(ReferenceSheet!$H$2:$H$9);ReferenceSheet!$H$2:$H$9);1)`